# Calling a function using variables from other functions as parameters/arguments

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters, arguments

I am trying to call a set of subroutines I created which use arguments from other subroutines. For example, the variable 'username' should be able to be passed into 'db_username_searcher'.

```
def signer():           
  def login():
    username = entry_user.get()  
    password = entry_user.get()  
    if username in admin_array:
        admin_pass = 'pass'  

    return username, password, admin_pass


win = tkinter.Tk()
win.title('Sign In')  
win.geometry('800x800') 
lbl_user = tkinter.Label(win, text='Username ')  
entry_user = tkinter.Entry(win)

lbl_pwd = tkinter.Label(win, text='Password ')
entry_pwd = tkinter.Entry(win, show='x')  
lbl_output = tkinter.Label(win)
btn_signin = tkinter.Button(win, text='Sign in', command=login)
lbl_user.pack()
entry_user.pack()
lbl_pwd.pack()
entry_pwd.pack()
lbl_output.pack()
btn_signin.pack()
entry_user.focus_set()

win.mainloop()
```

This is the code where 'username' is assigned and returned:

```
def db_username_sercher(username, password):

conn = sqlite3.connect('passwordDbase.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM passwordDb WHERE employee_username=?", (username, ))

r = c.fetchone()

if r:
    message = 'correct'

else:
    message = ' '

if message == 'correct':
    dbpassword = c.execute("SELECT employee_password FROM passwordDb WHERE employee_username=?", (username, ))
    if dbpassword == password:
        message = 'correct'

    else:
        message = ' '

conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
return message
```

When I try to call the two functions, I am not aware of how to deal with the arguments:

```
signer()
db_username_searcher(username, password)

"unresolved reference 'password' "
```

How do I call this properly?, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is not formatted properly. Please insert necessary indents after you define `db_username_searcher`

Comment: sorry, your code is badly formatted. I can't follow the flow. But did you intended to define username and password as global variables? If so, you should declare them as global in function `login()`, where you overwrite them

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways you could do this.

One: You need to add a line of code before the call to `db_username_earcher()` where you `catch` all of the variables `return`ed by `signer()` into a `list`/multiple variables. Then, you could pass username by using the list index or the variable you assigned to catch username.

Two: You could use `global` variables, and your `signer()` function could simply overwrite username, so that you can pass username in without any difficulties.

EDIT (in response to comments):

To `catch` the variables, you could do `a, b, c = signer()`, where `a` would contain the value of `username`.

About the list method, I meant that you need to `return` a list instead of three variables, and then you can directly reference `username` by using `your_caught_list[0]`.

Comment: I am trying to avoid global variables. Does it change anything due to the fact that the variables I want are in login which is in another subroutine signer? I tried to add to a list using " list = [signer.login.username]" but it doesn't work.